# Flutter Command can't run in VS Code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

after updating the flutter, I cannot run commands from VS Code
but when running at the command prompt can be run
information please[image]

Answer (score 1):

[check **update your path**](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#update-your-path)

You need to set environment variables so that flutter can be accessed from anywhere

Hope this helps!